# How to find outliers in a series, vectorized?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, vectorization

I have a pandas.Series of positive numbers. I need to find the indexes of "outliers", whose values depart by `3` or more from the previous "norm".

How to vectorize this function:

```
def baseline(s):
    values = []
    indexes = []
    last_valid = s.iloc[0]
    for idx, val in s.iteritems():
        if abs(val - last_valid) >= 3:
            values.append(val)
            indexes.append(idx)
        else:
            last_valid = val
    return pd.Series(values, index=indexes)
```

For example, if the input is:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([7,8,9,10,14,10,10,14,100,14,10])
print baseline(s)
```

the desired output is:

```
4     14
7     14
8    100
9     14
```

Note that the `10` values after the `14`s are not returned because they are "back to normal" values.

**Edits:**

- Added `abs()` to the code. The numbers are positive.
- The purpose here is to speed up the code.
- An answer that doesn't exactly imitate the code may *be* acceptable.
- Changed the example to include another edge case, where the values slowly change by 3.

Comment: How do you determine exactly which is an outlier? Because the desired output you show, is simply `s[s>3]`

Comment: @joris, I added code that defines it exactly.

Comment: Your code gives the desired output. What is your exact need? Better solution?

Comment: That's an unusual definition of outlier.  So `pd.Series([10,-1e6,12,13,14])` should return `[12, 13, 14]`?  Are you missing an `abs`?

Comment: @justhalf: the code *does* produce the last 14.  Try it yourself.

Comment: please let me know if `14, 100, 10` is expected result (that is what returned by your code) for `pd.Series([10,14,11,10,10,10,12,14,100,14,10])`

Comment: @alko, yes. It's also what the code returns.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my original "vectorized" solution:

You can get the `last_valid` using [shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and numpy's [where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series([10, 10, 10, 14, 10, 10, 10, 14, 100, 14, 10])

In [2]: last_valid = pd.Series(np.where((s - s.shift()).abs() < 3, s, np.nan))
        last_valid.iloc[0] = s.iloc[0]  # initialize with first value of s
        last_valid.ffill(inplace=True)

In [3]: last_valid
Out[3]:
0      7
1      8
2      9
3     10
4     10
5     10
6     10
7     10
8     10
9     10
10    10
dtype: float64
```

This makes the problem much easier. You can compare this to `s`:

```
In [4]: s - last_valid  # alternatively use (s - last_valid).abs()
Out[4]: 
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      4
5      0
6      0
7      4
8     90
9      4
10     0
dtype: float64
```

Those elements which differ by more the +3:

```
In [5]: (s - last_valid).abs() >= 3
Out[5]: 
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7      True
8      True
9      True
10    False
dtype: bool

In [6]: s[(s - last_valid).abs() >= 3]
Out[6]: 
4     14
7     14
8    100
9     14
dtype: int64
```

*As desired.* ...or so it would seem, @alko's example shows this isn't quite correct.

#### Update

As pointed out by @alko the below vectorized approach isn't quite correct, specifically for the example `s = pd.Series([10, 14, 11, 10, 10, 12, 14, 100, 100, 14, 10])`, my "vectorised" approach included the second 100 as "not an outlier" even though it is in baseline.

This leads me (along with @alko) to think this can't be vectorized. As an alternative I've included a simple cython implementation (see [cython section of pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/enhancingperf.html#cython-writing-c-extensions-for-pandas)) which is significantly faster than the native python:

```
%%cython
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
cimport cython
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef _outliers(np.ndarray[double] s):
    cdef np.ndarray[Py_ssize_t] indexes
    cdef np.ndarray[double] vals
    cdef double last, val
    cdef Py_ssize_t count
    indexes = np.empty(len(s), dtype='int')
    vals = np.empty(len(s))
    last = s[0]
    count = 0
    for idx, val in enumerate(s):
        if abs(val - last) >= 3:
            indexes[count] = idx
            vals[count] = val
            count += 1
        else:
            last = val
    return vals[:count], indexes[:count]

def outliers(s):
    return pd.Series(*_outliers(s.values.astype('float')))
```

Some indication of timings:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([10,10,12,14,100,100,14,10])

In [12]: %timeit baseline(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 132 µs per loop

In [13]: %timeit outliers(s)
10000 loops, best of 3: 46.8 µs per loop

In [21]: s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100, 100000))

In [22]: %timeit baseline(s)
10 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit outliers(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.43 ms per loop
```

For more, see the [cython (enhancing performance) section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/enhancingperf.html#cython-writing-c-extensions-for-pandas) of the pandas docs.

Comment: That's not what the current code does, though: it gives 3 14, 7 14, 8 100, 9 14.

Comment: `s = pd.Series([10,14,11,10,10,10,11,14,100,14,10])` is another good edge-case example

Comment: The main point is that `last_valid` from the question is recursively defined and imho can't be evaluated with vectorized approach

Comment: Fixed both those edge cases, by initialising last_valid as s.iloc[0]. Please let me know if you find some more edge cases! :)

Comment: @AndyHayden don't beleive you fixed for the second one (there must have been 12, not 11, if you compare for >=3, I worked with strictly greater) :) first 14 in `14, 100, 14` by op's definition is then not an outlier.

Comment: @alko This answer matches the code which the op gives... I agree that this is unusual definition of "norm" (I think I get what different defn you're hinting at, and I think a vectorised soln to that is analogous to this answer but doing the backwards first).

Comment: @AndyHayden for `pd.Series([10,14,11,10,10,10,12,14,100,14,10])` OP's code returns `14, 100, 10` and yours `14, 14, 100, 14`

Comment: @alko confusingly I see a different result when doing the OP's code (it matches mine).

Comment: @AndyHayden, thanks for your answer, but see my last clarification. I added `7,8,9` to my example to make clear that if the values slowly change by 3, then it's not an outlier.

Comment: @Yariv why Andy Hayden answer didn't receive bounty?

Comment: @lowtech, because there are 3 more days for the bounty.

Comment: @alko think I was just missing an abs in the second part, this should be correct now in your example!

Comment: @AndyHayden I still don't beleive last_valid can be computed with vectorized approach. My next try :) `s = pd.Series([10,14,11,10,10,12,14,100,100,14,10])`

Comment: @alko I *see*, good example, hmm you could be right (damn)... will have another think about this. If this was me, I guess I would consider cythonising. Grumble!

Comment: My intuition lines up with @alko's.  I don't think it's possible to write this in a vectorized way, because the value of `last_valid` for a given `iloc` can theoretically depend on a value arbitrarily earlier in the Series being considered.

Comment: does it mean my answer is not vectorized one?

Comment: @DJ_8one6 I agree, I added a cython solution which is pretty fast. But looks like it can't truly be vectorized: annoying.

Comment: @lowtech looks like it, try alko's example. It was my misunderstanding (last_valid can't ever increase by more than 3 each step, which means ffill doesn't really work)

Answer (score 2):

My attempt to solve the problem is to formulate it like recurrent expression for last_valid then follow Andy Hayden path. Expression for last_valid would be:

```
lv[i] = lv[i-1] if diff >= 3 else v[i]
```

where

```
diff = abs(v[i] - lv[i-1]))
```

where i is iteration number. To implement this in DataFrame I am using pointer from ctype.
Via dereferencing on shifted column of pointers to column lv (last_valid) the value calculated on one iteration step is accessible on next one.

```
from ctypes import *
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'s_num': [7,8,9,10,14,10,10,14,100,14,10]})
df['s'] = df['s_num'].apply(c_long)
df['lv'] = [c_long(0) for x in range(len(df))]
df.ix[0, 'lv'] = df.ix[0, 's']
df['p_lv'] = df['lv'].apply(pointer)
df['p_lv_m1'] = df['p_lv'].shift()

def ff(x):
    if not pd.isnull(x['p_lv_m1']):
        diff = abs(x['s'].value - x['p_lv_m1'].contents.value)
        x['p_lv'][0] = x['s'] if diff < 3 else x['p_lv_m1'][0]
    return None

df.apply(ff, 1)
df['lv_num'] = df['lv'].apply(lambda x: x.value)
df = df[['s_num', 'lv_num']]

print df.ix[(df['s_num'] - df['lv_num']).abs() >= 3, 's_num']
```

Comment: Nice to learn about ctypes. Note that Andy's solution is 10 times faster.

Comment: @Yariv I didn't try to build fast solution rather general solution for kind of problems where recursive defined action has to be applied. Advantage is if you will decide to change outlier criteria to use more than one point (smoothing) than in my approach it is easy to do.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using ctype? I've never seen it used either. I've seen [cython used to get similar-style speed boosts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/enhancingperf.html), one benefit being you are accessing numpy arrays directly (`.apply(c_long)` seems like a hack here and I think you lose performance). Would like to upvote, but this solution is too verbose/confusing/magical for me! Needs some explanation :)

Comment: if python would have id() supported with dereference op defined it would be not that cluttered. whole trick is within ff func: via pointers it is possible to get access to previous row values. sorry no time for more, maybe later next year i will have a chance to explain myself better.